# Using pandas.io.pytables.TableIterator for several iterations

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing method that takes a pandas iterator and then computes something based on that. The problem is that some of these computations require iterating twice over the data.

For example the normalized variance needs to first iterate over the data to compute the mean, and then iterate again to compute the (normalized) variance with that. I want to have the iterator as input because otherwise I'd need to compute the `select()` within the method which is quite some overhead I don't want to deal with.

However, I cannot reset `tableIterator`: it does not support `seek(0)`. Therefore, I'm running with a generator right now. Here's how it looks:

```
def computeIterativeMean(iterator):
    # computes the mean given an iterator
    n, mean = 0, 0
    for chunk in iterator:
        nCurrent = len(chunk)
        meanCurrent = chunk.mean()
        mean = (n * mean + nCurrent * meanCurrent)/(n + nCurrent)
        n += nCurrent
    return mean


def computeIterativeMoment(iteratorGenerator, n=2):
    # computes some moment given iterator generator
    mean = computeIterativeMean(iteratorGenerator())

    iterator = iteratorGenerator()
    i, moment = 0, 0
    for chunk in iterator:
        iCurrent = len(chunk)
        momentCurrent = ((chunk - mean)**n).mean()
        moment = (i * moment + iCurrent * momentCurrent)/(i + iCurrent)
        i += iCurrent
    return moment
```

And the code is called from outside as

```
    movementsIteratorGenerator = lambda: store.select(
        'movements',
        where=where,
        columns=myCols,
        iterator=True,
        chunksize=chunksize
    )

    mean = computeIterativeMean(movementsIteratorGenerator())
    variance = computeIterativeMoment(movementsIteratorGenerator, n=2)
```